# Save inner class of querySelectorAll as variable

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, selectors-api

This site uses underscorejs to fill the search results. The HTML looks like:

```
<li class="listing">
<input type="radio" class="representative" name="storeid" value="<%= store %> <%= address %> <%= address2 %> <%= city %> <%= state %> <%= zip %> <%= phone %> <%=sales_rep_email%> ">
<label  class="store_name"><%= store %></label>

<% if ( sales_rep_email ) { %>
<div class="sales_rep_email"><%= sales_rep_email %></div>
        <% } %>
</li>
```

The following code provides the value from the radio input. However, how can I retrieve and save the results of div.sales_rep_email as a variable to use on the next page?

```
function getStore(){
var items = document.querySelectorAll('input.representative:checked');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
alert(items[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send it with a request for the next page. The easiest way to do that is to wrap your form in `<form action="urlToNextPage" method="get">` element. This way all the information from your inputs will be automatically passed to the next page as URL parameters when calling the next page through submit buttons, without a need of any javascript at all.

Comment: Thank you Michal. However, I need the div with class sales_rep_email separately as well. Or a way to wrap the email within the Value to retrieve it separately. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2258848 you can do it with a hidden input: `<input type="hidden" name="salesRepEmail" value="<%= sales_rep_email %>">`

Comment: Almost Michal. Since this is a list, there can will be four different results with a Sales Rep email. I added the hidden input, however, it does not send value of the item selected. That's the tricky part. ???